# Meaning of 足に来る in sexual joke

Tags: meaning, manga, jokes

Context: a boxer is giving "advice" to another boxer and his girlfriend. He says:

> 戦う前にイチャつくとぜって〜モチベに影響するからな――
>   彼女[と]【・】は**足に来る**からそれも要注意な　風俗体験記

After this, the boxer laughs and the girl blushes. I don't know how to interpret 足に来る, so I can't understand the joke. On Kenkyusha dictionary I found this example:

> 疲れが足に来る one's feet show the effects of fatigue.

But in the sentence in question there's no noun+が before 足, so I don't know if this is the right meaning. Also, why is that と stressed?

Note that the boxer that is speaking is a 素人童貞, a man who has never had sex except with sex workers.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAAyb.jpg) you can see the whole page. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is 疲れが足に来る, literally "fatigue coming to the legs". We also commonly say 腰に来る and 首に来る without explicitly saying 疲れが. Of course 頭に来る means something different.

If I understand the context correctly (the speaker is a heavy 風俗 user), と is emphasized probably because leg fatigue happens only in the case of 彼女とする ("having fun *together with* a girl", i.e. intercourse), as opposed to 彼女がする/彼女にしてもらう (i.e. acts/services in which a man doesn't have to move).

Comment: So, practically... he means that イチャつく is ok before a match, but not 彼女とする, because you will tire your legs, right?

Comment: Also, what about 風俗体験記? Does it mean "I'm saying this because I experienced it in 風俗"?

Comment: Since the guy is saying 帰れ, perhaps he believes イチャつく affects the motivation *negatively*, but I need more context to be sure. Yes this 風俗体験記 seems to imply "I experienced it in 風俗".